# California Freemason Records

Tags: fraternal-organization, california

I have been told that my great-grandfather was a Mason in California, and that it is possible to request such records. I have no information on how to actually do that, and haven't had much success. How might I go about getting any such records?

Comment: I edited your message to take out the 'thanks', because SE doesn't seem to be into that kind of thing. (Hint to newcomers: you can say 'thanks' by  upvoting the answers you find helpful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a related question [How to find out which Freemasons' lodge grandfather belonged to?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/4210/1006) which has some general resources.

You are likely to receive the same kind of information that is found on the **[Massachusetts, Mason Membership Cards, 1733-1990](http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=5061)** database on Ancestry.com:

> These cards contain last residence information, birth date and
>   location, death date, the lodge an individual belonged to, date of
>   membership, and occupation. Once you determine a local lodge
>   affiliation, it may also be worthwhile to learn where their records
>   are archived. Clues like dates of residency, birth and death dates,
>   and offices held in the organization may be included in the lodge’s
>   historical records.

If you don't have information about your great-grandfather's Mother Lodge in your historical records, see if you can find out from an obituary or newspaper article.

If you don't know your great-grandfather's Mother Lodge, the next place to try is the [Grand Lodge of California](https://www.freemason.org/aboutUs/contact.htm). Unlike the Grand Lodge of Texas (from the linked question), there doesn't seem to be a link for Genealogy requests.  The contact information is:

> **Grand Lodge of California**
>
> 1111 California Street
>   San Francisco, CA 94108 
>   415/776-7000

The person who usually answers the genealogical inquires is the Membership Secretary.

Lodges, like many organizations, are set up to serve the needs of the present-day members.  They generally don't have archivists who can pull a member's file and send you a copy, like getting a government record from NARA. But it is still worth asking -- the Membership Secretaries in Scotland confirmed the information I already had from the Massachusetts database and gave me residence information I didn't have yet (and were very cordial while answering my inept inquiries).

Also in an [answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/4211/1006) to the linked question is the [Masonic Library and Museum Association](http://www.masoniclibraries.org/linkcatalogs.php) website.  There are three California entries in their list of [Member Sites](http://www.masoniclibraries.org/memberlink.php).