# What lodge did my grandfather belong to?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, new-york-state, fraternal-organization

What lodge did my grandfather Jac C Holman belong to in New York State in the twentieth century?

Does that lodge currently accept women in the twenty-first century?

Comment: Hi Nanine, it is helpful to explain where you have looked already, so you don't just receive answers that direct you to look at places you have already looked. Clearly you must know more, because you know he belonged to a Lodge. New York is a big state, can you narrow things down geographically? Does this question help: [Finding out which Freemasons' lodge ancestor belonged to?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4210/) Feel free to [edit] your question with any additional info.

Comment: I think your second question should be easy to answer by asking that lodge whether it currently accepts women.  Consequently, I think the focus of the question should be to find out which lodge you grandfather belonged to.