# Determining if ancestor was freemason in Pennsylvania

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, pennsylvania, fraternal-organization

All my life my dad and grandfather told me that my 2nd great grandfather was a Freemason, His name was Solomon Leighty he lived 1840 till 1885 in Westmoreland county Pennsylvania. He lived in or near Mount Pleasant.

Is there any way to verify that information?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! You could also try some of the further research ideas in my answer to https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/4210/1006

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @sempaiscuba](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/determining-if-ancestor-was-freemason-in-pennsylvania#comment25547_16245) you could try contacting the [Grand Lodge of Pennsylvania](https://pagrandlodge.org/) to ask if they hold any records for your 2nd great grandfather.

At the bottom of its home page there is an email address listed:

> **Research/Genealogy Requests**
>
> Email GIR@pagrandlodge.org