# Researching Masonic membership

Tags: new-york-city, fraternal-organization

My great uncle's name etc:

- Louis Napoleon Senor
- Born in Pysely Czechoslovakia July, 21, 1883
- Died Sept 28, 1937

Cemetery:
Cedar Grove Cemetery, Jennings Avenue, Patchogue, Suffolk County, New York

His headstone is inscribed with a Masonic Symbol (square and compass with a G).

His last address:
Yaphank Medford Rd, Brookhaven, Suffolk, New York, USA (Long Island).

How can I research his Masonic membership?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! We already have several questions on the site regarding membership in the Masons.  Please review this question [Finding out which freemasons lodge ancestor belonged to](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/4210/1006) to get clues for further research and then edit your Q to add any other research effort you've done and/or to say why the answers were not sufficient to help you.  You can learn more about how the site works by reading our [help] and our companion [meta].